# iOS 8 iCloud container change

Tags: ios, ios8, icloud, xcode6, xcode6-beta6

I have a couple of questions regarding iCloud in iOS8.

1. I am going through my developer profile and the iCloud container that was associated with my profile has been changed from my `${TeamIdentifer}{Bundle Name}` to `iCloud.{Bundle Name}` . Currently, my application is running only in iOS7 devices. So, if I use this `iCloud.{Bundle Name}` container, then would the content present in `${TeamIdentifier}.{Bundle Name}` be copied to the new container for users ?
2. Also, I am using xCode 6 beta 6 and it is not recognizing my `${TeamIdentifier}.{Bundle Name}` iCloud container. It is most probably because of my developer profile. I am planning to deploy the application for both iOS7 and iOS8. So, is there any way to change the iCloud container to `${TeamIdentifier}.{Bundle Name}` ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I'm having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. No one know for sure for now, I am currently will keep using the old style since it seems to work on iOS 8
2. You can change it on entitlements.plist file see here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AboutEntitlements.html

Comment: I tried doing that. However, it is still not recognizing my old container. In my developer profile, only the "iCloud." container is listed (maybe Apple changed that) and I am unable to add a container which does not begin with "iCloud". So, is there any way to associate the old container ?

Comment: weird, mine shows both. Is your app new (created using only xcode 6 beta)?

Comment: nope. It has been present in AppStore for about a year now.

Comment: I have the same problem as @Max. Xcode forces you to use iCloud as prefix for iCloud container.  When I use the new iCloud identifier, my app cannot access the iCloud documents that were saves using the old container with the TeamIdentifier as the prefix